# After checking the box "Require SSL, Ignore Client Certificates", I cannot reach my site. I am getting a 403 Forbidden error, Why?

Tags: ssl, iis

This all started when I was trying to do a HTTPWebRequest to a Web Service. I was debugging my project and I received an error "The requested resource can only be accessed via SSL". So, I did some more trouble shooting and I found that my SSL Setting on server for the site was not checked for "Require SSL". So, I checked the "Require SSL" and the button Ignore Client Certificates. Now my HttpWebRequest returns a 403 Forbidden error, as well as the trying to access the site in the browser. What can to do further troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I am pretty certain this is the case, I did not do this, but how can I check?

Comment: yes, we definitely have this set up, also I went into Advanced settings and enabled "https".

Comment: Are you definitely using HTTPS scheme in your URL?  The __Require SSL__ option only blocks you from using HTTP (non-TLS)  - it doesn't enable TLS in any way.

Comment: yes my URL Is "Https://intranet.somesite.com/ssc/webapi/"

Comment: Never use "Require SSL" but HTTP to HTTPS redirection.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, with not using Require HTTPS, but even I write code to redirect to HTTPS, in this instance it doesn't matter because I am trying to access the site using HTTPS in my URL and the site I am accessing has filters in their config files to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Require SSL  the option to choose when you want to enable two way mutual ssl authentication. Means the client needs to send it's certificate as well which will be authenticated by the server and then only the client will get access. In your case you wanted https to be mandatory whenever someone accesses your site. For that redirects can be created from http to https.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your response.